# How to delete the item?

Tags: database, hibernate, grails

Hi I have 2 domains in grails app, which is related and I got the problem when I tried to delete items.

```
Event {
       String eventName;
       Date eventDate;
       Fee eventFee ; 

       constraints = {
          .... 
          eventFee(nullable:true);
       }
    }
```

and

```
Fee{
   String feeName ; 
   ..... 
}
```

My problem is when I tried to delete the fee, even if there are no event that attached to that, it will raise en erorr : ConstraintException.

How to solve the problem and how to link between those 2 domains ?

ps: I am using grails 1.2xxx and database mysql

Comment: Can you post more details about the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably happens because the Fee object that you are trying to delete is being referred to by some Event object. You can see the Events by the following (pseudo-)code:

```
def fee = Fee.get(<id>) 
Event.findAllByEventFee(fee).each {
    println it
}
```

You can then set the eventFee to null for each event and delete the fee:

```
event.eventFee = null
fee.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the relationship is miscoded, you should refered to Fee in

```
Event {
   String eventName;
   Date eventDate;
   static hasOne=[eventFee:Fee] ; 

   constraints = {
      .... 
   }
}
```

And

```
Fee{

   String feeName ; 
   ..... 
}
```